# Код ошибки при завершении приложения -113

Tags: ios, qt, xcode

Qt проект, в том числе и для iOS. Если на айфоне завершить программу принудительно (свайпом вверх после перехода к листингу запущенных программ), то возвращается результат исполнения == -113.

```
int execRes = app.exec();
```

Что означает эта константа?

Comment: предположу, что это значит, что xcode потерял связь с приложением :)

Comment: в данном слечае может быть и так, но мы ещё получали отчёты об ошибках с логами с таким кодом завершения

Answer (score 1):

Exec() на самом деле цикл, который завершает работу , когда вы вызываете quit или exit.
При нажатии на кнопку Close("X") в окне, затем вызывается exit(0). Поэтому цикл завершается событие.

Так что, скорее всего, вы не создали главный виджет.

Если вы сделали,тогда проверьте свой ​​код в других частях приложения.
Вполне возможно, что у Вас где-то сформирован бесконечный цикл.

```
#include <QPushButton>
...
Здесь вы пишете код вашего приложения
...
QPushButton btn("Temporary button", NULL);
btn.show();
...
Здесь часть, где вы вызываете exec.
```

Comment: Интерфейс приложения на qml. В main.cpp перед запуском app.exec() загружается основное окно
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
...
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
int execRes = app.exec();

в main.qml корневой компонент ApplicationWindow {...}